# Is this a typo in Mastering Monero.pdf

Tags: sub-address

I can't figure out the meaning of this line in chapter 5.3.4:
`This subaddress public spend key is multiplied by the primary private spend key to yield the subaddress public view key:`

Because the notations are like below:
`PVi = pV0 * PSi`

The sentence shows **private spend key** but the notation is **pV0**.

Is it a typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a mistake. It should read:

*This subaddress public spend key is multiplied by the primary private **view** key to yield the subaddress public view key*

Comment: By the way, in [5.3.4.3 Receiving to a subaddress], Is it another mistake:

To ascertain whether a given output X (with public transaction
key R) was sent to the primary address, the wallet checks calcu-
lations based on its the **public** view key and public spend key.

Because the notation is in low case: `X==Hs(pV0 *R)G+PS0`

Comment: @Mooooo You're right, that's another mistake. All of the algebra in that section is correct, but they said public instead of private where you indicated.